# Android data class unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, data-class

I have a data class below -

```
data class MyViewState(
    val loading: Boolean = false,
    val data: String? = null,
    val error: String? = null
)
```

I have a simple JUnit4 test -

```
@Test
fun testLoading() {
    val myViewState = MyViewState()
    myViewState.copy(loading = true)
    assertEquals(myViewState.loading, true)
}
```

The test fails. Gives me -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :false
Actual   :true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking the value in the original object. Use this:

```
@Test
fun testLoading() {
    val myViewState = MyViewState()
    val myViewStateCopy = myViewState.copy(loading = true)
    assertEquals(true, myViewStateCopy.loading)
}
```

Also note your expected value should be the first parameter to `assertEquals()`

Answer (score 1):

Your assert is checking the value of myViewState which has not changed.

Store the result of `copy` in a new object and test against that.

```
@Test
fun testLoading() {
    val myViewState = MyViewState()
    val myNewViewState = myViewState.copy(loading = true)
    assertEquals(myNewViewState.loading, true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're testing the old object, not the copied one.

**Do this instead:**

```kotlin
@Test
fun testLoading() {
    val myViewState = MyViewState()
    val myViewStateCopy = myViewState.copy(loading = true)
    assertEquals(true, myViewStateCopy.loading)
}
```